# What does “value” mean in the following context?

Tags: meaning

> **Create Value**
>
> *“Strive not to be a success, but rather to be of value.”*
>
> Most people approach the word “success” wrongly. It’s not just being
>   bare-wealthy and having big firm who runs mechanically without your
>   existence. Success is about getting all mentioned before, step by
>   step, so we will be able to appreciate those things while we create
>   and sustain them.
>
> Someone of value inspires others to live the right way and do the
>   right thing. Live in accordance with one’s religious, philosophical,
>   or spiritual values. A person of value has ethics, morality, decency,
>   integrity, principles and honesty. All those things one should strive
>   to attain.

Comment: What did you not understand about that last paragraph?

Comment: The author of your quote defines exactly what he means by both *success* and *value*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

'Value' has a number of meanings. Firstly it can be a verb... you can value something, but it can also be a noun, something has value... and it has the related adjective, valuable. Furthermore the verb 'to value' can mean either 'to hold something as valuable to yourself' or 'to ascertain the value of something'.

In one respect it is synonymous with price... 'What is the value of your house?, or 'I'm having my house valued'.

In a subtly different way, value is seen as the combination of price and quality. 'A good quality product at a low price... that's good value'.

But value can also refer to human qualities, both as a noun and a verb. 'I really value your friendship' 'Your friendship is valuable'.

And separately again, it can be a set of concepts which you hold to have value, like morals. 'He had strong values'.

The passage you posted deliberately mixes these different meanings by placing the word value in a context (about business) where it would normally mean price and asking you to consider that value can be about the less tangible benefits you bring as a person and your morals. What it's saying essentially is that you shouldn't just aim to build up a lot of money (success) but you should aim to be valued by those around you.